# Looking for Firebase Notification FirebaseMessaging UserInfo Fields Documentation

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-notifications

I am looking for details on FirebaseMessaging and what the meaning of the fields we receive in userInfo

I can manage to map and reverse engineer some of the fields below, but I would prefer to have documentation on the structure

I cannot find here
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasemessaging/api/reference/Classes/FIRMessagingMessageInfo

```
  ▿ 0 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("google.c.a.c_l")
      - value : "google.c.a.c_l"
    - value : MyMessageLabel
  ▿ 1 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("MyFirstKey")
      - value : "MyFirstKey"
    - value : MyFirstValue
  ▿ 2 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("MySecondKey")
      - value : "MySecondKey"
    - value : MeSecondValue
  ▿ 3 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("google.c.a.e")
      - value : "google.c.a.e"
    - value : 1
  ▿ 4 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("google.c.a.ts")
      - value : "google.c.a.ts"
    - value : 1502794207
  ▿ 5 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("google.c.a.udt")
      - value : "google.c.a.udt"
    - value : 0
  ▿ 6 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("gcm.n.e")
      - value : "gcm.n.e"
    - value : 1
  ▿ 7 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("aps")
      - value : "aps"
    ▿ value : 1 element
      ▿ 0 : 2 elements
        - key : alert
        ▿ value : 2 elements
          ▿ 0 : 2 elements
            - key : title
            - value : MyKeys
          ▿ 1 : 2 elements
            - key : body
            - value : MyMessage
  ▿ 8 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("google.c.a.c_id")
      - value : "google.c.a.c_id"
    - value : 6841195152614788722
  ▿ 9 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("gcm.message_id")
      - value : "gcm.message_id"
    - value : 0:15027942336070%49e9e09f49e9e09f
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the FCM HTTP protocol. The documentation for it is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref).